# Use backbutton eventListener in svelte

Tags: javascript, event-handling, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to implement a scroll to last position functionality when the user clicks on the backbutton in the browser. So in my App.svelte, I created a window binding like this:

```
<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} on:backbutton={e => console.log('FIRED')} />
```

My problem is that it does not work. Is there another way to use eventListeners or listen to this specific event?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as the `backbutton` event. If you've manipulated the history using `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState` then you can listen for the `popstate` event, but otherwise there's no way to change the behaviour of the browser's back button.

Comment: I am using svelte-router, so I have to check what this does under the hood.